# After upgrading to 1703, the system crashes after a few seconds with KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

Tags: bsod, windows-10-v1703

I upgraded my HP Probook 6470b to Windows 1703, and now after a few seconds after starting the system, it bluescreens with KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED.
Safe mode works fine.
I was able to get the full memory dump and the stack tarce seems to be corrupt:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffd2015fc70110 -- (.exr 0xffffd2015fc70110)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000b92b9910
   ExceptionCode: 00000002
  ExceptionFlags: ffff86c3
NumberParameters: -844038016
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000101
   Parameter[1]: ffffa40997a1e3a0
   Parameter[2]: fffff805f497f000
   Parameter[3]: ffff77318af429ec
   Parameter[4]: 0000acbc000de000
   Parameter[5]: ffffd2015d317fc8
   Parameter[6]: fffff8008c90729d
   Parameter[7]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[8]: fffff8008c6c53a0
   Parameter[9]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[10]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[11]: 00000000000005ec
   Parameter[12]: ffffd2015fc70220
   Parameter[13]: fffff800899f7957
   Parameter[14]: ffffe609cb37fb40

TRAP_FRAME:  0000000005846b00 -- (.trap 0x5846b00)
Unable to read trap frame at 00000000`05846b00

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80089a02baa to fffff800899edfd0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd201`5fc6f8f8 fffff800`89a02baa : 00000000`0000001e ffffffff`c0000005 fffff800`8c68d288 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd201`5fc6f900 fffff800`899f9482 : ffffd201`5fc70110 00000000`00000000 00000000`05846b00 ffffa409`97b75e00 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x174c8a
ffffd201`5fc6ffc0 fffff800`899f7957 : ffffe609`cb37fb40 ffffe609`ce17f080 ffffe609`ce222080 00000000`00000524 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
ffffd201`5fc701a0 fffff800`8c68d288 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x217
ffffd201`5fc70330 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : 0xfffff800`8c68d288
```

Comment: You should immediately roll back to 1607.  1703 has not been officially released, you should wait until your offered the update through Windows Update, you will avoid this problem if you do that.

Comment: @Ramhound How to do this? When attempting to do this from recovery optins „a problem occured and we can’t recover previous version of windows”

Comment: This does not seem to be a driver issue. I managed to disable all third-party drivers (set Start=4 in registry) and windows still crashes when not in safe mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some incomprehensible reason, disabling and then re-enabling [secure boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx) in the BIOS seems to have solved the issue.